# Wifi proof with WeMos D1 ESP8266 Ad-Hoc

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am trying to use a WeMos module to send a broadcast message through an peer-to-peer network (Ad-Hoc). The thing is that i can't give a SSID nor Password to that network, i just can define it through them IP Addresses. As you suspect i don't have a specific idea of the configuration of the Wemos module.

**What am I talking about?**

I need to receive messages in a IEEE802.11 software-defined radio module. In this module I can't establish a network, just listen to a channel, and read whatever someone is sending. Think about it as a sniffer. But in this case i can assign to this module a MAC and IP within the Network.

**What do I need?**

I need just to:

```
Initialize peer-to-peer (Ad Hoc) network without an SSID nor Password.
Set a channel (I do it with channel 13, it is most times free).
Send a broadcast message in that channel to the SDR module in the network.
```

**In other words**
Module SDR:
 - IP:192.168.123.2
 - MAC: xxx
Wemos
 - IP:192.168.123.3
 - MAC: xxx

Through Wemos:

- wifi, send broadcast message

The mask is /24, then it is going to send the message to all IPs from 192.168.123.2 to 192.168.123.254, then, for sure to the SDR Module, and i could receive it.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Cristian

Comment: if there's not a formally connected peer, i doubt it would bother to broadcast. Look into the Nrf24L01, or even the 433Mhz wireless modules; they naively broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

ESP8266 does not currently support Ad-Hoc/IBSS mode.